# Need further insight on functional dependencies

Tags: dependencies

I'm trying to solve the below question , but I need a little more insight on functional depend-ices. I have goggled it and have some understanding of it, but I need to further apply my understanding.

**Question:**

- *Find all functional dependencies (includes bijections, one-to-one correspondences, mappings) within tbl 01 ?*

**Here is a line items from tbl 01:**

```
Member Zip = 2919   MemberCountycode= OT  ZipCountyClass= Class1
```

Sorry if my  format is off, but when I tried paste the table in the column format was lossed.

**So far I have I came up with this:**

```
{
   Member Zip -> MemberCounty Code
   MemberCountyCode -> ZipCountyClass
}
```

I'm still a bit stumped on bijections and the rest of the question.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Anyone has insight on this?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say with your example. Especially when it has some use-case specified.

I can only give example with UNF type record for cart item like this:

Cart_item

- cart_id
- user_id
- user_name
- product_id
- product_name
- product_type
- quantity
- unit_price

the functional dependency will be like:

- product_name, product_type -> product_id
- user_name -> user_id
- quantity, unit_price, product_id, user_id -> cart_id

This will defined that the record structure can be divided into 3 tables: products, users and cart_items. It described that each record (product, user, cart_items) is representing 1 unique record each and it will prevent duplication/redudancy.

In your case, it seems that both the dependency is false. Why is it:

- One country code can has many zip code
- One Country class can has many country code or zip code